# get latest password values from key vault when caching in place in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, azure-keyvault

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. I have used KeyVault to fetch latest secret for database passwords. I am able to fetch password from in `global.asax` App Start method & set/replace same password in connection string.

Now I have also used Caching library to cache secrets to avoid multiple calls to Keyvault. So password will get updated in 5 days in database as well as in Keyvault then it will throw exception that incorrect credentials (due to caching).

So what will be the ideal place & way to call Keyvault?

Answer (score 0):

> So what will be the ideal place & way to call Keyvault?

In general, you can call key vault using

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider 
                  = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
 
KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient 
      = new KeyVaultClient(new
         KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback
         (azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback)
);
 
//To get the secrets
string url = "https://<KeyVault>.vault.azure.net/";
var secretItems = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretsAsync(url);
return View(secretItems.ToList());
```

While Caching responses from Key Vault, you may cache and proxy secrets, keys, and certificates from Azure Key Vault using a `HttpPipelinePolicy`.

```
SecretClientOptions options = new SecretClientOptions();
options.AddPolicy(new KeyVaultProxy(), HttpPipelinePosition.PerCall);

SecretClient client = new SecretClient(
    new Uri("https://myvault.vault.azure.net"),
    new DefaultAzureCredential(),
    options);
```

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Use Azure Key Vault with an Azure web app in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app)
2. [Cache certain responses from Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/azure-key-vault-proxy/)